# In Wolverine Origins, couldn't wolverine just cut away the flesh surrounding the cut made by the Muramasa and regenerate?

Tags: comics, marvel, wolverine

I was reading the Wolverine Origins comic where Captain America cuts Wolverine with the Muramasa blade. The cut, as it is revealed will not heal because of the blade. If Wolverine were to cut out everything around the wound, wouldn't his regenerative ability heal him? I'm currently unaware if this is done later in the comics as I haven't read that far.

Comment: Without knowing the details, I might ask, it the blade magical? I would think you're proposal that he could cut out the wound stands to reason unless there is a magical element to the blade.

Comment: According to this [entry](http://marvel.wikia.com/Muramasa_Blade), it has a portion of wolverines soul. But no talk of magical abilities. I haven't seen anything in the comic to backup the statement that his wound healed after a while.

Answer (score 5):

**No, Wolverine could not cut away the damaged tissue and regenerate normally. Once exposed to the weapon, any injuries he caused himself would only add to his misery.**

- [The Muramasa Blade](http://marvel.wikia.com/Muramasa_Blade) (we are discussing the second one, not the first) suppresses the healing factor of mutants such as Wolverine, Daken (Wolverine's son) and Sabertooth, so any injury caused by the blade could not be artificially healed.
- Any injuries made with it took days to heal, indicating the healing factor of their mutant abilities were nearly completely suppressed. Creed had his arm cut off with the Muramasa Blade and was unable to reattach it (as he did when Wolverine cut off his arm with his claws).
- The process by which it suppresses the mutant powers has not been clearly identified and has been speculated as a disruption of molecular structures preventing regeneration to "its magic". Given the blade's ability to cut almost any normal substance except memory-oriented constructs (psionic or magical) magic would be the most likely origin for the physical properties of the weapon.

Comment: +1 However, I think the question then becomes whether the suppression applies just to the wound itself (or some modest area around the wound) or to the entire organism (or such a large area around the wound that it might as well be the entire organism). It seems the OP guessed that it might only apply to a modest area around the wound.

Comment: If you dig a hole then try to dig around it, you are only making a bigger and wider hole?